# Django - Running pip as the 'root' user can result in broken permissions

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, virtualenv, version

I'm deploying my Django backend utilizing the AWS app runner service. The contents of my files are as follows.

**apprunner.yaml**

```
version: 1.0
runtime: python3
build:
  commands:
    build:
      - pip install -r requirements.txt 
run:
  runtime-version: 3.8.16
  command: sh startup.sh
  network:
    port: 8000
```

**requirements.txt**

```
asttokens==2.2.1
backcall==0.2.0
category-encoders==2.6.0
certifi==2023.7.22
charset-normalizer==3.3.0
colorama>=0.2.5, <0.4.5
comm==0.1.3
contourpy==1.0.7
cycler==0.11.0
debugpy==1.6.7
decorator==5.1.1
distlib==0.3.7
executing==1.2.0
filelock==3.13.0
fonttools==4.40.0
gunicorn==20.1.0
idna==3.4
ipykernel==6.23.2
ipython>=7.0.0, <8.0.0
jedi==0.18.2
joblib==1.2.0
jupyter_client==8.2.0
jupyter_core==5.3.0
kiwisolver==1.4.4
matplotlib==3.7.1
matplotlib-inline==0.1.6
nest-asyncio==1.5.6
numpy==1.24.2
opencv-python==4.7.0.68
packaging==23.0
pandas==1.5.3
parso==0.8.3
patsy==0.5.3
pickleshare==0.7.5
Pillow==9.5.0
pipenv==2023.10.24
platformdirs==3.11.0
prompt-toolkit==3.0.38
psutil==5.9.5
pure-eval==0.2.2
pycodestyle==2.10.0
pygame==2.1.3
Pygments==2.15.1
pyparsing==3.0.9
python-dateutil==2.8.2
pytz==2022.7.1
pyzmq==25.1.0
scikit-learn==1.2.1
scipy==1.10.0
seaborn==0.12.2
six==1.16.0
stack-data==0.6.2
statsmodels==0.13.5
threadpoolctl==3.1.0
tornado==6.3.2
traitlets==5.9.0
urllib3>=1.25.4, <1.27
virtualenv==20.24.6
wcwidth==0.2.6
whitenoise==6.4.0
```

**startup.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
python manage.py collectstatic && gunicorn --workers 2 backend.wsgi
```

By the way all the packages are installed successfully in the AWS app runner, finally it gives

```
10-29-2023 02:39:34 AM [Build] [91mWARNING: Running pip as the 'root' user can result in broken permissions and conflicting behaviour with the system package manager. It is recommended to use a virtual environment instead: https://pip.pypa.io/warnings/venv
10-29-2023 02:39:34 AM [Build] [0mRemoving intermediate container 4a0110123b9d
10-29-2023 02:39:34 AM [Build]  ---> fca9ca934529
10-29-2023 02:39:34 AM [Build] Step 5/5 : EXPOSE 8000
10-29-2023 02:39:34 AM [Build]  ---> Running in c8a4669398b0
10-29-2023 02:39:34 AM [Build] Removing intermediate container c8a4669398b0
10-29-2023 02:39:34 AM [Build]  ---> 1f0d784181f3
10-29-2023 02:39:34 AM [Build] Successfully built 1f0d784181f3
10-29-2023 02:39:34 AM [Build] Successfully tagged application-image:latest
10-29-2023 02:42:13 AM [AppRunner] Failed to deploy your application source code.
```

However I changed the apprunner.yaml code to include virtualenv as

```
version: 1.0
runtime: python3
build:
  commands:
    build:
      - pip install pipenv
      - pipenv install -r requirements.txt
run:
  runtime-version: 3.8.16
  command: sh startup.sh
  network:
    port: 8000
```

but then the apprunner fails and gives errors even without installing the packages:

```
10-29-2023 02:29:06 AM [Build] Warning: the environment variable LANG is not set!
10-29-2023 02:29:06 AM [Build] We recommend setting this in ~/.profile (or equivalent) for proper expected behavior.
10-29-2023 02:29:06 AM [Build] Warning: Python 3.11 was not found on your system...
10-29-2023 02:29:06 AM [Build] Creating a virtualenv for this project...
10-29-2023 02:29:06 AM [Build] Pipfile: /codebuild/output/src2729792062/src/backend/Pipfile
10-29-2023 02:29:06 AM [Build] Using default python from /root/.pyenv/versions/3.9.16/bin/python3.9 (3.9.16) to create virtualenv...
10-29-2023 02:29:06 AM [Build] created virtual environment CPython3.9.16.final.0-64 in 1333ms
10-29-2023 02:29:06 AM [Build]   creator CPython3Posix(dest=/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/backend-C4VHmbmy, clear=False, no_vcs_ignore=False, global=False)
10-29-2023 02:29:06 AM [Build]   seeder FromAppData(download=False, pip=bundle, setuptools=bundle, wheel=bundle, via=copy, app_data_dir=/root/.local/share/virtualenv)
10-29-2023 02:29:06 AM [Build]     added seed packages: pip==23.2, setuptools==68.0.0, wheel==0.40.0
10-29-2023 02:29:06 AM [Build]   activators BashActivator,CShellActivator,FishActivator,NushellActivator,PowerShellActivator,PythonActivator
10-29-2023 02:29:06 AM [Build] ✔ Successfully created virtual environment!
10-29-2023 02:29:06 AM [Build] Virtualenv location: /root/.local/share/virtualenvs/backend-C4VHmbmy
10-29-2023 02:29:06 AM [Build] Warning: Your Pipfile requires python_version 3.11, but you are using 3.9.16 (/root/.local/share/v/b/bin/python).
10-29-2023 02:29:06 AM [Build]   $ pipenv --rm and rebuilding the virtual environment may resolve the issue.
10-29-2023 02:29:06 AM [Build] Usage: pipenv install [OPTIONS] [PACKAGES]...
10-29-2023 02:29:06 AM [Build] ERROR:: Aborting deploy
10-29-2023 02:29:16 AM [AppRunner] Failed to deploy your application source code.
```

so I changed the `runtime-version` in apprunner.yaml to 3.11.0 then the apprunner gives:

```
10-29-2023 01:43:46 AM [AppRunner] The specified runtime version is not supported. Refer to the Release information in the App Runner Developer guide for supported runtime versions.
```

So I'm confused between installing virtual env and versioning problem in AWS apprunner. However I followed this [blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/deploy-and-scale-django-applications-on-aws-app-runner/) to deploy and scale Django applications on AWS App Runner.

Comment: No need for this `pip install pipenv`, python supports virtual environments out of the box. Use the built in [venv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) module instead. Create a virtual environment and activate the virtual environment in your apprunner.yaml. See my answer for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
build:
  - pip install pipenv
  - pipenv install -r requirements.txt
```

To this

```
build:
  - python -m venv /path/to/new/virtual/environment
  - cd /path/to/new/virtual/environment
  - Scripts\activate
  - pip install -r requirements.txt
```

reference: [python docs Virtual Environments and Packages](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html#virtual-environments-and-packages)

Comment: I'm getting `[AppRunner] The specified runtime version is not supported. Refer to the Release information in the App Runner Developer guide for supported runtime versions.` issue continuously. But according to the documentation (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apprunner/latest/dg/service-source-code-python-releases.html) I tried both 3.8.16 and 3.8.5 as runtime-version with your updated code. But getting the same error :/

Comment: @Damika your issue stems from here now. `run: runtime-version: 3.8.16 •••`. Although I need you to confirm that `build:` command works correctly now. Let’s see if we can work on `run:` command.